# ImageMagick convert out of memory

Tags: linux, imagemagick, out-of-memory

I have a custom application runnning on CentOS 6.7 with 64 GB of RAM, which is basically a file crawler that calls  the following bash script every time it finds a file matching some file extensions(mainly TIFFs or multipage TIFFs).
I can't tell exactly the frequency and how many files are been considered, but it's in the order of thousands.

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGE_INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2
TMP_FOLDER=/data/tesseract-tmp

# generating a unique random file name
TFN=`cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 32`;
# converting the image and putting the result into the TFN
/usr/bin/convert -density 288 "$IMAGE_INPUT" -resize 75% -quality 100 -append jpeg:$TMP_FOLDER/$TFN;
# extract text with tesseract and put it into a result file
/usr/local/bin/tesseract $TMP_FOLDER/$TFN $TMP_FOLDER/$TFN.out;
cp $TMP_FOLDER/$TFN.out.txt $OUTPUT;
# returning the file content to std output
cat $OUTPUT;
```

The temp files are being cleaned by a cronjob.

I have noticed that after some time and a lot of calls to the script, the top command shows me that the **gs** and **convert** processes of imagemagick are taking all the memory available, and they start to consume all the swap space available.
If I don't kill those processes the system runs out of memory and freezes.

How can I solve this situation?
Is there a way to limit the amount of memory for a particular program(convert) or is there the possibility to queue the execution of calls to the script?

N.B. I have seen that there is the limit option for the convert command, but if I'm understanding right, it applies to the single instance of the running process, while I would like to **limit** the memory usage for the whole running instances.

Thanks

Comment: »… after a lot of calls to the script …«?  Have you tried cleaning up after each call to the script?  Maybe some processes (gs and convert) linger and aren't needed anymore, so killing them with `kill` or `killall` should be no problem.

Comment: I'll try with kill, because I can't killall as I would end up killing also the other processes that are still running...

Comment: What is `-append` doing here? Why don't you use `tmpnam` to generate temporary files?  Why don't you delete the temporary files when you are finished so you don't clag up your filesystem with junk?

Comment: Hi Mark, the append is because input may be a multipage tiff. Didn't know of tmpnam, but should it change the situation? The temp files are deleted by a cronjob.

Comment: Good job updating your Q, but things are still vague. So multiple copies of `myScript` can be running at the same time? You need to quantify this stuff. Why not add a `echo "started processing $file at $(date)>$logFile; myScript ; echo "Done processing $file at $(date) > $logfile` wrapper around `myScript` . You could also do `(echo $(date) ;  while (( i++ > 100 )) ; do ps -ef | grep -E 'gs|convert' ; sleep 1 ; echo $(date) ) > processesInfo.txt` (or similar) to see how many are running at the same time . Good luck.

Comment: »… as I would end up killing also the other processes that are still running …« Forgive me, but are you starting a lot of stuff in parallel?  If so, the explanation is easy and the solution simple.  You run out of memory because each parallel process needs some of it at the same time, and: Just start less (or nothing) in parallel.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it by using the following command:

```
nice -20 /usr/bin/convert -limit memory 32 -limit map 32 -density 288 "$IMAGE_INPUT" -resize 75% -quality 100 -append jpeg:$TMP_FOLDER/$TFN;
```

This way the memory il fully occupied but it never starts swapping, and the system never freeze.

Thanks anyway to Mark Setchell answer, it's been useful and appropriate for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using **GNU Parallel** to limit the memory use and improve the speed by running jobs in parallel . Basically, it won't start another parallel job till the specified amount of memory is free.

So, assuming your script is called `OCR` and it takes an input filename as parameter:

```
parallel --memfree 1G OCR {} ::: *.tif
```